# How to send data through PendingIntent to Broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to send via `PendingIntent` some extra data, like:

```
MyMessage message;
//...
Intent intent;
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
intent = new Intent(Constants.SENT_PLAIN);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_RAW_ID, message.getId()); //putting long id (not -1L)
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent, 0);
intent = new Intent(Constants.DELIVERED_PLAIN);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_RAW_ID, message.getId());
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent, 0);
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message.getBody(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Then in `Broadcast` trying to catch data:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message, prefix = "";
    String action = intent.getAction();
    long id = intent.getLongExtra(Constants.EXTRA_RAW_ID, -1L);  //here I receive id=-1

    // blah-blah.... 
}
```

I see that `Broadcast` `onReceive()` called - which means that `Broadcast` registered in a proper way, but still extras are empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have done something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver/14612215#14612215

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Put data in intent you are using in pending intent as Extras.
You will get this intent in `onReceive` Method of `BroadCast` receiver.
Try to define Pending intent as below.

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Sir. You have saved me a couple of debugging hours. Thank you!

Comment: You saved my day, but it sound weird, getBroadcast

Comment: Will this object persist in the broadcast receiver even if our app is closed?

Comment: @FarazAhmad Yes It will persist.

Comment: Thanks for 'PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT'

Answer (score 11):

as said on [pending intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) :

> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does *not* happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by [`Intent.filterEquals`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)). If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per [`Intent.filterEquals`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)), then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
>
> There are two typical ways to deal with this.
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   [`Intent.filterEquals`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)), or different request code integers supplied to
>   [`getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)), [`getActivities(Context, int, Intent\[\], int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivities(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent[],%20int)), [`getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)), or
>   [`getService(Context, int, Intent, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)).
>
> If you only need one PendingIntent active at a time for any of the
>   Intents you will use, then you can alternatively use the flags
>   [`FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) or [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) to either cancel or modify
>   whatever current PendingIntent is associated with the Intent you are
>   supplying.

Answer (score 1):

### Anyone who are experiencing getting null extras in Broadcast Receiver:

You should use
`FLAG_MUTABLE`

Here is an example:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
     context,
     0,
     intent,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE //not FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
```