# Pending intent broadcast not going through

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a broadcast when a pause button on a notification is clicked. The notification is fired from a background service that controls a music player.

This is the notification.

```
private void showPlayerNotification() {
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(Constants.RADIO_SERVICE_ACTION_RECEIVER);
    pauseIntent.putExtra(Constants.RADIO_SERVICE_ACTION, RadioService.PAUSE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(new MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setColorized(true)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.player_background))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(mediaStream.getStreamName())
            .addAction(R.drawable.notification_pause, "Pause", pausePendingIntent);

    Notification mediaNotification = notificationBuilder.build();
    startForeground(1, mediaNotification);
}
```

The broadcast receiver is defined in the Service and is registered with an intent filter `Constants.RADIO_SERVICE_ACTION_RECEIVER`. I use the same broadcast receiver successfully to control playback where the broadcast originate from an activity.

The above `pauseIntent` broadcast is not getting through to the broadcast receiver. Could it be that the service context causing the issue?

> I have successfully received the intent in my player activity by using a `PendingIntent.getActivity` but I don't want to handle it in the activity as that might mess the activity code.

Comment: Check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752538/how-to-send-data-through-pendingintent-to-broadcast

Comment: My issue is not related to sending data. The pending intent is not getting through to the broadcast receiver, and my two pending intents differ through the action action signature and the request code.